# Is there Data Panel in Blend for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: data-binding, visual-studio-2012, blend

I was looking in http://visitmix.com/labs/rosetta/eyesofblend/datatemplates/ tutorial for to add sample data to project. But I can not find Data panel. Is there Data panel in Blend for VS2012? Or can I add sample data in some other way?

Comment: Are you making a HTML or XAML (WPF or Jupiter) application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design time data is not available on all platforms. Windows Store App don't have the Data panel available in Blend for Visual Studio 2012. The XAML namespaces for creating sample data are available, so you could create design time data from code. Have a look at [this to tutorial](http://www.irisclasson.com/2013/02/03/a-simple-design-time-data-example-with-windows-store-applications-for-beginners/) on how to do that.

It won't be of any help working with Blend for Visual Studio 2012, but in the next version of Blend support for design time data is added.

Comment: Blend for VS2013 Preview has Design Time Data support.